# Setting variable in a command reading from a pipe

Tags: windows, batch-file

Consider this batch file:

```
@echo off

echo Separate lines:
set line=previous value
echo new value|set /p line=
set line

echo Same line:
set line=previous value
echo new value|(set /p line=&set line)
```

Output:

```
Separate lines:
line=previous value
Same line:
line=new value
```

Why doesn't the new value assigned to a variable on the right-hand side of a pipe "stick"?

Comment: Whilst I'm sure that your example is created just for the purpose of your question, why use `echo new value|set /p line=` instead of `set "line=new value"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve this with a pipe, as both sides of a pipe are executed in a new cmd.exe instance.

Therefore your sample `echo new value|(set /p line=&set line)` shows that the text is stored into the line variable and can be output from that instance.
But after the pipe is done, both cmd instances are destroyed and your line variable is lost.

If you want to fetch from pipe input outside your batch file you could use a FOR loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set line=original
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ('more') do set "line=%%L"
echo !line!
```

Test with

```
echo New Text | myBatch.bat
```